# Reading website table comes with a list name "NULL" in R

Tags: html, r, web

I want to read a table directly from a webpage with R. In reader's view the webpage with the table looks like this:

[image]

I used two packages to read the table from the webpage. It worked OK except the fact that the table is read as a list.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
d<-getURL('https://securewordpresswebsiteAddress/data/')
d<-readHTMLTable(d, header=T)
```

Here is what I get after reading the table

```
> d
$`NULL`
    ID      X       Y Depth    P
1 1046 256857 2632323    13  2.8
2 1054 257090 2632039    13  1.1
3 1057 257099 2631981    13  2.6
4 1058 257071 2632004     9  2.1
5 1060 257173 2632004    13    4
6 1089 257194 2631660    13 14.1
```

Where is this $`NULL` coming from? is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: `websiteAddress` does not seem to resolve in my browser. it wouldn't be a site that prohibits scraping, would it?

Comment: no i gave a fictitious link, the webpage is not prohibiting scraping

Comment: Someone else will likely take your word for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually returning a list of named elements, based on the makeup of your HTML table.

```
> readHTMLTable('~/htmltest.html', header=TRUE, as.data.frame=FALSE)
$`NULL`
$`NULL`$`ID`
[1] "1046" "1054" "1057" "1058" "1060" "1089"

$`NULL`$X
[1] "256857" "257090" "257099" "257071" "257194" "257194"

$`NULL`$Y
[1] "2632323" "2632039" "2631981" "2632004" "2632004" "2631660"

$`NULL`$Depth
[1] "13" "13" "13" "9"  "13" "13"

$`NULL`$P
[1] "2.8"  "1.1"  "2.6"  "2.1"  "4"    "14.1"
```

So when you use `as.data.frame = TRUE` it coerces this list of elements into another list containing a data.frame. Since the HTML table does not have an `id` associated to it, it is named `NULL`.

Fix this by adding an `id` inside the table tag when you write your HTML table, like so `<table id='sometable'> .. </table>`

```
> readHTMLTable('~/htmltest.html', header=TRUE, as.data.frame=TRUE)

$`sometable`
    ID      X       Y Depth    P
1 1046 256857 2632323    13  2.8
2 1054 257090 2632039    13  1.1
3 1057 257099 2631981    13  2.6
4 1058 257071 2632004     9  2.1
5 1060 257194 2632004    13    4
6 1089 257194 2631660    13 14.1
```

The HTML file I am reading contains the following table:

```
<table id='sometable'>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>X</th><th>Y</th><th>Depth</th><th>P</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1046</td><td>256857</td><td>2632323</td><td>13</td><td>2.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1054</td><td>257090</td><td>2632039</td><td>13</td><td>1.1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1057</td><td>257099</td><td>2631981</td><td>13</td><td>2.6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1058</td><td>257071</td><td>2632004</td><td>9</td><td>2.1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1060</td><td>257194</td><td>2632004</td><td>13</td><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1089</td><td>257194</td><td>2631660</td><td>13</td><td>14.1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: so how to avoid that problem of "NULL" while writing HTML file?

Comment: To avoid this, the table should contain an id inside its tag. I adjusted my answer to show this.